# Json if else remove or hide class and add class

Tags: javascript, json

I tried using json, with remove class logic, and add class using if else condition.

below, a sample code on script, where if condition is a message page, "myclass" is not displayed, if else "myclass" is displayed. "So, I just want to hide myclass if it's in pages messages.

can someone tell me, or correct the code below, or is there another logic?
I would be very grateful.

```
if (json_data.page == 'messages') {
  $('.myclass').removeClass();
 } else {
$('.myclass').addClass();
                     }
```

Comment: What are the contents of `json_data.page`?

Comment: of course, you need an argument to addClass, right? - because the argument is *mandatory* in addclass ... in removeclass, your code removes **every** class from every element with class that includes `myclass` ... which means there's no elements with `.myclass` left for `addclass` to add classes to if this is some sort of "toggle"

Comment: perhaps you meant to use `show/hide`

Comment: you are brilliant sir Jaromanda. This is i mean, thank you so much